# Conditional Attributes is ignored for data- ... Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following on a Razor View:

```
<div data-key="@Model.Key">@Model.Name</div>
```

When Model.Key is null data-key should not be rendered. However, it is as data-key="". I then checked ASP.NET MVC source and it is being ignored for data:

https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor/Parser/HtmlMarkupParser.Block.cs#L493

Why is that?

Comment: Didn't undertand ... But if I change data-key to class or id then it works fine ... wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div @( (Model.Key == null) ? "" : "data-key='"+ Model.Key +"'" )>@Model.Name</div>
```

Hope it works.